# How To Format A Decimal Number With Exponential factor?

Tags: java, android, decimal, decimalformat

I have this number

> 1.2345679E6

How can I format it to 
1.23E6 using `DecimalFormat`?

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ["E" `DecimalFormat` formatting specifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to specify scientific notation, with a "0" on the end.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##E0");
System.out.println(df.format(1.2345679E6));
```

This outputs:

```
1.23E6
```